# SQL - Update table values from values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a select statement that is showing me all the data from table original every time it does not match the values on table real_values.

So every time it does not match, instead of showing me which routes have the wrong values for capacity, I would like the query to update it with the correct values.

Here is a shorter version to use as an example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a904/1

Instead of being a select statement, how could I just update the values? I have tried some things I've seen online but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidFaber's answer is how most people would do this. However, for this kind of query, I prefer to use `merge` over `update`:

```
MERGE INTO original o
USING      real_values rv
ON         (o.origin = rv.origin AND o.destination = rv.destination)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET
      o.capacity_wt = rv.capacity_wt, o.capacity_vol = rv.capacity_vol
      WHERE         o.capacity_wt != rv.capacity_wt
                 OR o.capacity_vol != rv.capacity_vol
```

(It was unclear to me from your question whether you want to update `original` or `real_values`, so I chose one. If I got this wrong, reversing it should be trivial.)

I find `merge` more readable and easier to use when you want to update multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

The usual form of such an update query in Oracle is the following:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET t1.value = ( SELECT t2.value FROM table2 t2
                     WHERE t2.key = t1.key )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
                 WHERE t2.key = t1.key );
```

I'm confused though. You've tagged this question `oracle` and `sql-server` but your fiddle link uses MySQL.

Comment: Will it be more efficient if dump the EXISTS operator and add condition like "t2.value is not NULL"?

Comment: I don't see why it would.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, but still it makes no sense having to do a select statement per value I want to update? If I want to update 4 values, I would need a select per value?

Comment: @randomizertech: You can update in sets: `set (value1, value2) = (select value1, value2 from...`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would do this

```
update original set capacity_wt=b.capacity_wt,capacity_vol=b.capacity_vol
from original a, real_values b
where a.origin = b.origin 
and a.destination = b.destination 
and (a.capacity_wt != b.capacity_wt
or b.capacity_vol != b.capacity_vol);
```

Comment: I get an error saying 'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'

Comment: So, you are using Oracle and not SQL Server